# Is it possible to get rid of recursion in my Combinations extension? Or maybe it is not needed at all?

Tags: c#, recursion, combinations, extension-methods, ienumerable

I have written a small Extension class for generating Combinations of elements (no repetitions and no permutations). I use recursion and I wonder how to get rid of it and if it is needed at all. Could it be that C# compiler will convert it into iterations though (the methods does not seem to be tail-recursion)? Here is the class:

```
public static partial class Extensions
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Combines elements of all sizes starting from 1 and up to the number of elements.
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T"></typeparam>
    /// <param name="items">Elements to be combined.</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> Combinations<T>(this IEnumerable<T> items)
    {
        var i = 0;
        foreach (var item in items)
        {
            i++;
            yield return new[] { item };
            foreach (var sub in Combinations(items.Skip(i)))
                yield return new[] { item }.Concat(sub);
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Combines elements only of a given size.
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T"></typeparam>
    /// <param name="items">Elements to be combined.</param>
    /// <param name="size">Size of the combination.</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> Combinations<T>(this IEnumerable<T> items, int size)
    {
        int i = 0;
        foreach (var item in items)
        {
            i++;
            if (size == 1)
                yield return new T[] { item };
            else
            {
                foreach (var result in Combinations(items.Skip(i), size - 1))
                    yield return new T[] { item }.Concat(result);
            }
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Combines elements of sizes from a given min to a given max.
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T"></typeparam>
    /// <param name="items">Elements to be combined.</param>
    /// <param name="min">Min size of combination.</param>
    /// <param name="max">Max size of combination.</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> Combinations<T>(this IEnumerable<T> items, int min, int max)
    {
        int i = 0;
        foreach (var item in items)
        {
            i++;
            if (max == 1)
                yield return new T[] { item };
            else
            {
                if (min <= 1)
                    yield return new T[] { item };
                foreach (var result in Combinations(items.Skip(i), min - 1, max - 1))
                    yield return new T[] { item }.Concat(result);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you describe why you want to eliminate the recursion?  It's certainly possible but it would be helpful to understand your concerns before proposing a solution.

Comment: Let's put it like that. I must admit that I have not dedicated a lot of time to re-write these recursions and I am pretty sure that they can be re-written with iterations but at what price or maybe benefit? At the same time 'combinations' should be a well-known thing so maybe somebody has already an optimized out-of-the-box solution. As for concerns, recursions can eat up stack memory and result in StackOverflowException.